# Развернуть код на pythonanywhere.com на bipwallet

Tags: python, плагин, pythonanywhere

Я написал код для генерации дочерних адресов кошельков биткоинов. На pythonanywhere он работает с ошибкой, ошибка формата. Почему-то уверен, из-за отсутствия плагина

В чём, собственно, и вопрос: как его туда подтянуть?

Но тот же код на Pydroid + Repository Plugin работает отлично. В чём причина?

#### Вот код:

```
from bipwallet.utils import *

def gen_address(index):

    # Наша seed фраза
    seed = 'vivid area able second bicycle advance demand alpha flip stable drift route'

    # Мастер ключ из seed фразы
    master_key = HDPrivateKey.master_key_from_mnemonic(seed)

    # Public key из мастер ключа по пути 'm/44/0/0/0'
    root_keys = HDKey.from_path(master_key, "m/44'/0'/0'/0")[-1].public_key.to_b58check()

    # Extended public key
    xpublic_key = str(root_keys, encoding="utf-8")

    # Адрес дочернего кошелька в зависимости от значения index
    address = Wallet.deserialize(xpublic_key, network='BTC').get_child(index, is_prime=False).to_address()

    rootkeys_wif = HDKey.from_path(master_key, f"m/44'/0'/0'/0/{index}")[-1]

    # Extended private key
    xprivatekey = str(rootkeys_wif.to_b58check(), encoding="utf-8")

    # Wallet import format
    wif = Wallet.deserialize(xprivatekey, network='BTC').export_to_wif()

    return address, str(wif, 'utf-8')

print(gen_address(0))
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blacar/Blacar/blockchain", line 35, in <module>
    print(gen_address(0))
  File "/home/blacar/Blacar/blockchain", line 20, in gen_address
    address = Wallet.deserialize(xpublic_key, network='BTC').get_child(index, is_prime=False).to_address()
  File "/home/blacar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bipwallet/utils/utils.py", line 67, in _c
    f.cache[key] = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/blacar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bipwallet/utils/bip32.py", line 320, in get_child
    data = self.get_public_key_hex()
  File "/home/blacar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bipwallet/utils/bip32.py", line 155, in get_public_key_hex
    return ensure_bytes(self.public_key.get_key(compressed))
  File "/home/blacar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bipwallet/utils/keys.py", line 240, in get_key
    long_to_hex(parity, 2) +
  File "/home/blacar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bipwallet/utils/utils.py", line 53, in long_to_hex
    return ensure_bytes(f_str.format(l).lower())
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to mpz.format
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки (что вообще за "ошибка формата"?)

Comment: В сам вопрос, не в комментарии. Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, нажмите [edit] под ним.

Comment: Исправил , спасибо

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте вместе с полным стетрейсом. В стектрейсе указывается в каком именно месте возникает ошибка.

Comment: Dобавил , пожалуйста ^